# Vertical sum of column

Tags: report, rdlc

I'm creating a report using RDLC, I need to sum up all the months column.

i.e. the row showing total should come after Dec-21, Sep-21...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the month group, you just need to add a group total, like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypr9D.png)